# Unable to send URL to chrome

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing some Selenium script in Java. Here I'm using options, But unfortunately, I'm unable to send URL to the browser using `options`. And when i run it normally, I'm able to send it. Below is my Code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
        // System.out.println(user);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver cd = new ChromeDriver(options);
        cd.get("http://google.com");
```

When I run this, I'm getting the below Exception.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1) on port 39621
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.43 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.1', revision: 'd80083d', time: '2015-10-08 21:07:25'
System info: host: 'U0138039-TPD-A', ip: '10.112.78.15', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
    at EaselTest.main(FirstTest.java:20)
```

But when I run the below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();
        cd.get("https://google.com");
```

It is working fine with no error.

And also, the browser starts maximized, but the URL is not sent to browser. This is quite confusing. please let me know how can i fix this. This worked for me some time ago(like an Hour or so..), but now it is not. And the error is thrown at `WebDriver cd = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Please let me know when i went wrong and how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: It is working for me perfectly. I believe that it has something to do with your `user-data-dir` flag. Check the contents of the folder. Maybe try uninstalling and installing chrome after deleting the user `user-data-dir` folder contents.

Comment: Hi @Sighil, after some trial and error methods, came to this conclusion. If i'm opening chrome, doing browsing or listening to songs, this is happening, else it is working fine. please let me know how can i get this fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments in the question this looks like this is related to the user-data-dir. When wr are doing some operation on an open chrome browser some files are getting updated in the folder and getting used. So when u try to start chrome after pointing to the folder chrome crashes. If you are looking at using some extensions in the folder you can copy the folder and point it to the copy instead.

Comment: So you mean to say that, I need to make a copy of `user data` folder say `user data1` folder and access it, so that while browsing, still the data impact would be on `user data` folder, but not on `user data1` folder. please confirm me if my understandings are right or wrong.